# Connect to FTP Server via VBA, "Put" function for *.XLSB local file

Tags: excel, vba

Ive tried several different things ive found on here and nothing has worked for me like this one below:

```
Option Explicit
Const FTP_ADDRESS = "ftp.yourdestination.com"
Const FTP_USERID = "anon"
Const FTP_PASSWORD = "anon"

Sub Macro1()
    If Not SendFtpFile_F() Then
        MsgBox "Could not ftp file"
    Else
        MsgBox "Sent"
    End If
End Sub
Function SendFtpFile_F() As Boolean
  Dim rc As Integer
  Dim iFreeFile As Integer
  Dim sFTPUserID As String
  Dim sFTPPassWord As String
  Dim sWorkingDirectory As String
  Dim sFileToSend As String

  Const FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME = "myFtpFile.ftp"
  Const INCREASED_BUFFER_SIZE = 20480

  SendFtpFile_F = False

  sWorkingDirectory = "C:\YourWorkingDirectory\"
  sFileToSend = "NameOfFile.txt"


  On Error GoTo FtpNECAFile_EH

   'Kill ftp process file if it exists
    If Dir(sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME) <> "" Then
      Kill sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME
    End If

    'Create ftp process file
    iFreeFile = FreeFile
    Open sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME For Output As #iFreeFile
      Print #iFreeFile, "open " & FTP_ADDRESS
      Print #iFreeFile, FTP_USERID
      Print #iFreeFile, FTP_PASSWORD
      Print #iFreeFile, "mput " & sWorkingDirectory & sFileToSend
      Print #iFreeFile, "quit"
    Close #iFreeFile

    'Shell command the ftp file to the server
    Shell "ftp -i -w:20480 -s:" & sWorkingDirectory & FTP_BATCH_FILE_NAME

  SendFtpFile_F = True

  GoTo FtpNECAFile_EX


FtpNECAFile_EH:
    MsgBox "Err", Err.Name

FtpNECAFile_EX:


  Exit Function

End Function
```

Can anyone please assist. I need to connect to my "ftp server" and upload the same excel file (Closeout.xlsb) with the VBA code wrote in it. Nothing has worked for me.

File Location = C:\Goodman Input Files
File Name = Closeout.xlsb

Connecting to = "ftp.MyServer.com"

Need assistance,

Lock

Comment: You forgot to detail what _does_ happen when you tried it. Clarify it in your question (it _should_ be obvious, but don't email or call me please)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are **bad**! ;-)

Comment: It simply seems like it does nothing at all. Like it calls out and connects but thats it. I looked to see if it creates a upload txt file like it should to upload in the primary directory location. But nothing. So no code response or error or anything. I'm just not sure what is happening. I only know it does not work for me.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Bad like a _fox_!

Comment: same issue , it does nothing